# How to draw ellipse using svg.path with Path variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, svg, path, svg-animate

I got this list and this is what from which I have to create the Path variable in string format.

```
def trans_hatch_ellipse(dxf_entity, dwg) :
    tmp = dxf_entity.to_spline(False) 
    ctrlPoints = tmp.control_points
    ctrlCnt = tmp.control_point_count 
    strPath = "" 
    for i in range(ctrlCnt()) : 
        if i%4 == 0 : 
             strPath += "M " + str(ctrlPoints[i][0]) + " " +str(ctrlPoints[i][1]) + " C " 
        else : strPath += str(ctrlPoints[i][0]) + " " + str(ctrlPoints[i][1]) + " " 
    svg_entity = dwg.path(d = strPath, fill = "blue", stroke = "green", stroke_width = 1.0 / SCALE) 
    svg_entity.scale(SCALE, -SCALE) 
    del tmp 
    return svg_entity
```

This is what I used to draw an ellipse, here the value of ctrlCnt() = 9 and the value of ctrlPoints is given as VertexArray

```
VertexArray = [
(2.0, 4.500000000000001, 0.0),
(0.9999999999999998, 4.500000000000001, 0.0),
(0.9999999999999996, 2.5, 0.0),
(0.9999999999999996, 0.49999999999999956, 0.0),
(1.9999999999999998, 0.4999999999999991, 0.0),
(3.0, 0.49999999999999867, 0.0),
(3.0000000000000004, 2.4999999999999996, 0.0),
(3.000000000000001, 4.5, 0.0),
(2.0000000000000004, 4.500000000000001, 0.0)
]
```

This is the value that I read from a `.dxf` file to convert that into `.svg` file.

Using these coordinates, what value should I pass in Path variable to create ellipse shape?

Comment: I don't understand how do you want to create ellipse from so many values? Usually elipse need 4 values - `x1, y1, x2, y2` or `centerX, centerY, r1, r2`. How should look this ellipse? Or maybe it is list with many ellipses ? But they have only 3 values - so it could create onlu circle. What did you try? What module did you use? Where is your code?

Comment: def trans_hatch_ellipse(dxf_entity, dwg) :
    tmp = dxf_entity.to_spline(False)
    ctrlPoints = tmp.control_points
    ctrlCnt = tmp.control_point_count
    strPath = ""
    for i in range(ctrlCnt()) :
        if i%4 == 0 :
            strPath += "M " + str(ctrlPoints[i][0]) + " " + str(ctrlPoints[i][1]) + " C "
        else :
            strPath += str(ctrlPoints[i][0]) + " " + str(ctrlPoints[i][1]) + " "
    svg_entity = dwg.path(d = strPath, fill = "blue", stroke = "green", stroke_width = 1.0 / SCALE)
    svg_entity.scale(SCALE, -SCALE)
    del tmp
    return svg_entity

Comment: This is what I used to draw an ellipse, here the value of ctrlCnt() = 9 and the value of ctrlPoints is given as VertexArray in question

Comment: you should put it inquestion - it will be more readable. And more people will see it - so more peole can help you. You could even create minimal working code which we could run to see problem and test ideas. And then we can also see what modules you use and then we can search documentation for this module to read more about functions which generate SVG in this module. But it would be simpler if you would add link to module. You have to remember that we can't see your code, we can't see your screen, we can't read in your mind - so you have to add all details in question.